# React Native Swift Escaping closure

Tags: swift, react-native

I am trying to implement a native module in React native using Swift for IOS.

I have a function **getRandomFoodWithCompletionHandler()**
Where I am trying to fetch something from the API and then sending it back to JS through the bridge using promises.
I use **resolve:RCTPromiseResolveBlock** function, but when I use it I have an error
**Escaping closure captures non-escaping parameter 'resolve'**

[image]

```
struct Food: Identifiable, Decodable {
      var id: Int
      var uid: String
      var dish: String
      var description: String
      var ingredient: String
      var measurement: String
  }

  @objc
  func getRandomFoodWithCompletionHandler(_ resolve:RCTPromiseResolveBlock, reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {
      guard let url = URL(string: "https://random-data-api.com/api/food/random_food") else { fatalError("Missing URL") }

      let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)

      let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
          if let error = error {
              print("Request error: ", error)
        
              return
          }

          guard (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200 else { return }
          guard let data = data else { return }
          do {
               let decodedFood = try JSONDecoder().decode(Food.self, from: data)
               print("Completion handler decodedFood", decodedFood)
               
               resolve(decodedFood)
            
           } catch {
               print("Error decoding", error)
           }
      }

      dataTask.resume()
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your `resolve: RCTPromiseResolveBlock` parameter an escaping block:

```
func getRandomFoodWithCompletionHandler(
    _ resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
    reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock
) {
```

An "escaping" block is essentially a block that can be called even when the original function has already finished executing, e.g. when it's an asynchronous completion handler.
In Swift it's necessary to distinguish such a situation because of memory allocations/deallocations.